# To store the hex value entered in command line onto integer

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(int argc,char* argv[]){
        int hex;
        printf("\n argc : %d argv[1] : %s \n",argc,argv[1]);
        hex = argv[1];
        printf("\n hex : %x \n",hex);
        return 0;
}
```

o/p:

```
[root@ld]# ./a.out 343ed4

 argc : 2 argv[1] : 343ed4

 hex : 9e1a4aa8
```

I wanted to store the hex value got from the command line argument and store it on the integer. The above program , when stored the hex value gives a different result from the user given value.
Cant use atoi too as it would cut of the alphabets after the numbers. How to store the hex entered in the command line arguments into an integer.

Comment: [off topic], but why do you use a root shell for a program like this?

Comment: [off topic] I guessing --- because it's a minimum example?!?!

Answer (score 5):

This is incorrect:

```
hex = argv[1];
```

The compiler should have warned you about assigning a `char*` to `int`, because `argv[1]` is a string representation of a hex number (i.e. `{'3','4','3','e','d','4','\0'}`), not a hex number itself.

You need to do this:

```
sscanf(argv[1], "%x", &hex);
```

`sscanf` parses the hex number for you, and stores the result in `hex`.

Comment: Or, if you don't want all the overhead of sscanf, you can use strtol --  `hex = (int)strtol(argv[1], NULL, 16);`

Answer (score 4):

as per dasblinkenlight

You need to do this:

```
sscanf(argv[1], "%x", &hex);
```

BUT

sscanf returns the number of arguments (as in %x) successfully parsed. So I would add a check for it to be 1. If it isn't they entered something that could be parsed to hex.

```
printf("\n argc : %d argv[1] : %s \n",argc,argv[1]);
if (sscanf(argv[1], "%x", &hex)==1)
    printf("\n hex : %x \n",hex);
else
    printf("\nargv[1] is not a valid hex value.");
```

if you don't check the return value you will not pick up the point of failure in your code.

sscanf can be used to match patterns and extract the variable values from them like a date import for example:

```
int day, month, year;
int count = sscanf (inputstr, "%d/%d/%d", &day, &month, &year );
if (count!=3)
     printf("bad date value");
```

Comment: this would have been better as a comment to the other answer.

Comment: how would I of given the example code as a comment?

Comment: If code tests the result of `sscanf()`, might as well also test `argc > 1` or `argv[1] != NULL`.  Further, `strtol()` has even better error handing.  But is any case, looking for errors is a _good_ thing. +1

Comment: if code without regard for errors are you a coder at all?!